# I have excel sheet that I update with quarterly financial data. I want to automate the process of updating it each quarter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have two df one with time series of historical data (df1) the other with the recent year data (df2)

```
so for example 
df(1):
 Date   DebtGDP   Credit    Expenditure
 2020  0.053078  0.501184    757.000000  
 2021  0.935433  0.050437    229.000000 
 2022      NaN       NaN        NaN
 2023      NaN       NaN        NaN

df(2):
 Date   DebtGDP   Credit    Expenditure
 2022  0.056078  0.401184    757.000000
 2023  0.605842  0.661184    900.000000

I want df1 to read from df2 and update the recent ones
```

Wanted output:

```
df(1) would be:
 Date   DebtGDP   Credit    Expenditure
 2020  0.053078  0.501184    757.000000  
 2021  0.935433  0.050437    229.000000 
 2022  0.056078  0.401184    757.000000
 2023  0.605842  0.661184    900.000000
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: `out = df1.combine_first(df2.merge(df1[['Date']], how='right'))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas - merge two data frames overwrite and specify which columns to keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278630/pandas-merge-two-data-frames-overwrite-and-specify-which-columns-to-keep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = df1.combine_first(df2.merge(df1[['Date']], how='right'))
```

Or:

```
out = df1.set_index('Date').combine_first(df2.set_index('Date')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Date   DebtGDP    Credit  Expenditure
0  2020  0.053078  0.501184        757.0
1  2021  0.935433  0.050437        229.0
2  2022  0.056078  0.401184        757.0
3  2023  0.605842  0.661184        900.0
```